# Smallest file block size (ext 3, 4)

Tags: filesystems, ext4, ext3

I'm curious, what is the smallest size a file can really be on Linux? (Assuming Ext3 fs, so why not ext4 fs as well).

Sure you can write a file that only contains one byte, or maybe even less; but surely that'll allocates a minimum, and reasonable amount of data for convenience.

So what is the minimum allocation / block size that can be allocated on ext3, and or ext4?

Comment: `1024` is the smallest according to the `mke2fs` manpage. 4096 is the default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smallest possible allocation size for a file in ext3/ext4 is 0 (none at all) because of inline data: [files with sizes smaller than 60 bytes can be stores completely inside the inode itself](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inline_Data_2).

Of course, every file, whether it's a regular file, symlink, directory (which can contain data), or character device or block device or named pipe (none of which possess the concept of "contents"), still occupies an inode. You can read about [the size of the inode itself](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inode_Size).

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, it still misses the point. The inode itself uses space, and even worse: it seems that you can't have more than one inode per block. So ultimately a file still consumes one block, one way or the other, even if stored inside the inode. And the minimum block size of ext4 is 1024 bytes.

Comment: This comment is incorrect. There are almost always multiple inodes per block, blocksize/inode_size. For a default ext4 filesystem this is 4KiB/256B=16 inodes/block. With inline_data, larger inodes would allow more data to be stored directly into the inode. For huge numbers of very small files (eg. 100-1900 bytes) it might be worthwhile to format the filesystem with 512- to 2048-byte inodes so the data always fits in the inode, but after that it would be more flexible to stick with 256-byte inodes and 4KB blocks.