# Setting up ext4 filesystem to accomodate 100,000,000 files iNode issues

Tags: linux, ext4

I have a RHEL 9 with an ext4 fs

```
Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 1258291199 1258289152  600G 83 Linux
```

it has been requested it be ext4 with Inodes for 100,000,000 files +

I thought I could just run mkfs.ext4 -N 2000000000 /dev/sdb1

to get more than enough inodes however when I mount the partition

mount /dev/sdb1 /fileshare

the /fileshare shows up as only 92gb

when I run mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1 then mount it the /fileshare shows as 560gb which is what I want how can I get a inode count that I need to accommodate that large file count (100 million to 500 million) but still have the 560gb disk size?

Comment: With the default size 256 bytes for an inode, requesting that many inodes will take up about 476GiB. Switching to a different file system will not help you very much and might hurt. You'll need a larger disk to handle 5M files.

Comment: @doneal24 I think that your comment has answer qualities! I'd upvote it if you posted it as answer. (It would also allow the discussion of whether different filesystems would behave better to be kept there.)

Comment: Why `-N 2000000000`? Your question says your target is around the 100 million mark, not the 2000 million mark - you're asking for 20x more inodes than you need

Comment: How big are your files (on average)? Do you have enough disk space for 100 million of them? Even at a minimum of 1kB/file you're going to need 1TB storage just for the data

Comment: @doneal24 aaarrrgg yes I did not think that through I upped the fs to 1.6tb and used 1billion for -N and it is all good now

Comment: @MarcusMüller I considered this as an answer but it really does not answer the OP's question on how to set the filesystem to accommodate his needs, only why his commands don't work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why `-N 2000000000`? Your question says your target is around the 100 million mark, not the 2000 million mark - you're asking for 20x more inodes than you need. Fix that and you might get a reasonable result.

However, there is a bigger issue here with regard to file size. Although at a [minimum of 1kB/file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/191324/100397) you're going to need only around 125GB storage to hold that many files (including an approximation for the inodes, at 4x per kB), if we go with your example's 2x10^9 inodes then that's going to be 2.25TB. At least.

Comment: I'll argue that things get pretty specific at this number of files, and that maybe classical file systems simply are the wrong choice there; some kind of object storage might be

Comment: About 15-20 years ago I worked on a project where we captured photographs of vehicles. Between 2 and 5 photos each, and we had to keep them for a few years. A quick back-of-the-spreadsheet calculation suggests it might have been around 300,000 photos per year, and at even only 2MB/photo that's 500GB/year. We used a hierarchical directory structure simply to make it easier for our support staff to hunt through the photos. These days it might make more sense to use a bucket based solution or even a database but back then putting TB of image data into a database was questionable. @MarcusMüller

Comment: Maybe with inline data, a (very) small file would need just an inode and the direntry? [The docs seem to say](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inline_Data) you could put 60 bytes in an 128-byte inode, or maybe 160 bytes in a 256-byte inode... that's still at least 60 % overhead, so perhaps some other database format could offer better space utilization...

Comment: @ilkkachu apparently an inode is one block, so 1kB at best (and typically 4kB). It seems strange to me that inodes aren't packed multiples into a block, but that's what I've understood from [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191324/smallest-file-block-size-ext-3-4#comment1153267_191347) to one of the answers

Comment: @ChrisDavies, what, no, that wouldn't make any sense, I can't see where that idea would come from. Like the other answer says, the numbers given in the question work out for the default 256 B inodes (2*10^9 * 256 bytes =~ 500 GB). If the inodes were any bigger, they wouldn't even fit. I can't find a perfect quote from the docs, but the FS layout doc says the inode table is a linear array (though really it's split between block groups), and that "Each inode record can be as large as the filesystem block size, though this is not terribly efficient."

Comment: @ilkkachu that (what you've written) makes far more sense, thank you. (10^8 not 2x10^9, perhaps, though?)

Comment: We had a situation in-house where an individual needed 16+ million 7kb files. The EMC Isilon NAS allowed the creation of the directory tree but utilities such as replication, dedup, indexing, etc., all failed miserably. We eventually moved the data to a dedicated system using xfs as the underlying file system.

Comment: @MarcusMüller "object storage" is no miracle cure, most of them are just based on a regular filesystem underneath. At the lowest level, there needs to be space for metadata for each object and the data it holds, so at least 100M x (data size + metadata), and that isn't going to get much more efficient than ext4.

Comment: @ChrisDavies: (1) What? Doing the math on my fingers, 100 million × 1kB is 100GB, not 1TB.  (2) I agree that the question is bad.  But, given its focus on inodes, I suggest that we should at least *consider* the possibility that the user wants to have a huge number of zero-length files, where the filenames and metadata ***are*** the information to be stored.  (3) And note that [Celada’s nine-year-old answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/191347/80216) points out (and ilkkachu reaffirms) that a file can have 60 bytes of data without having any data blocks.

Comment: @LustreOne I've written things I would call "object storage" for measurement data recordings (at megasamples per second, so linearity of access was… important). Idea is ferociously simple: a simple off-device table in a file that maps recording ID to a 64bit unsigned start address and a length on a raw block device (in that case, that was an LVM2 volume); that table (I was lazy and just use sqlite, a good decision as it turns out) is the only thing you need to make atomically modifiable. That's what I had in mind when I said "object storage": a plain relational DB indexing linear memory.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' um, er, yes. I don't know how I slipped 10x there. Fixing

Answer (score 2):

You asked for 2 billion inodes  which at 256 bytes per inode is 476 GB of inodes.  ask for 500 million and it will be much better at only 120 GB of space for inodes.  You can even shrink the size of an inode `-I 128` but that comes with limitations, see [the `mkfs.ext4`/`mke2fs` man page for details](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/e2fsprogs/mkfs.ext4.8.en.html).

I would just use the `-i bytes-per-inode` option, and trust that you will get a good balance.